# What is $\int_0^1 K_0(a\,x) \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}}dx$ for $a,b>0$?

Tags: integration

Exactly as the title states: what is $$\int_0^1 K_0(a\,x) \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}}dx$$ for $a>0$ and $b>0$, where $K_0(x)$ is the usual modified Bessel function?

Bonus points for obvious generalizations such as $K_0\rightarrow K_\nu$, $x\rightarrow x^\mu$, $\sqrt{x^2+b^2}\rightarrow (x^2+b^2)^\rho$.  Extra bonus points for an actual derivation.

Thanks so much!

Comment: What have you tried? Where is this problem coming from? Why is it important?

Comment: Not listed in G&R, nor Olsen, nor Watson 1944.  $\int_0^1 dx\,K_0(a x)x^n$ evaluates to a very messy combination of $K_0$ and $K_1$ times some nasty hypergeometric functions, so a Taylor series of the ratio seems like it won't work.  I can't find a closed form solution for $\int_0^1 dx\,e^{-a' x} x/\sqrt{x^2+b^2}$, so using the integral representation of the Bessel seems unlikely to help.

Comment: If $|b|<1$ then you can Taylor expand the square root and sum up terms of the form $b_n \int_0^1 K_0(ax) x^{c_n} dx$. But it will be ugly. Generally integrals of this sort on bounded intervals are ugly except for the extremely special cases like https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.43#i